# swift xcode UIDatepicker

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

How do I get data picker to display and select the year also.

Currently I see the following but what I need is Year Mon Day HH MM

[image: ---- Click Here to See current view ----]

Comment: Hard to believe that this can't be answered by searching for it.

Comment: And pretty disappointing not to follow up when someone does that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`.datePickerMode = .date` or `.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime`

both are dependant on locale... so different countries will see different potentially undesirable formats.

[Swift Accessing year from UIDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247401/swift-accessing-year-from-uidatepicker?rq=1)

You can customise `UIPickerView` though if you need to...

[Can i customize UIDatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934477/can-i-customize-uidatepicker)